# How to apply css and keep that css to a textbox

Tags: css

I have a textbox with some css property created by formHandler method.
When I check the textbox is empty and I applied another css class for red color in the border through jquery code is below

```
 $('a,button').click(function () {
        if($("#FHE_0_first_name").val()=="")
            {
            $("#FHE_0_first_name").addClass("errorCSS");
            }
    });
```

and my css is below

```
.errorCSS
{
    clear:both;
    border:1px solid #ff0000 !important;
    background-color:#ffeeee !important;

}
```

The red color and background color just come and disappered how can i keep the neww css .

appreciated all suggestions

Comment: perhaps you should make a jsFiddle so we have a model to play with

Comment: from what you are saying it sounds like the style is being applied correctly but later on the style is being lost. could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to change your $(a,button) selector to $(a.button).

Comment: That's because the page will subit through 2 way one for a href and another for button click.I am tracking both the events.

Comment: $('a,button') is legit. it will select any anchor or button tag. see: http://jsfiddle.net/6r6cg/

Comment: I am getting the alert inside the function and even the css is also affected for a quick moment that is at the time of button click

Comment: You are right it will select any anchor tag...i  need to modify that too..My a href is something like below <a onclick="adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', 1); return false;" href="#">
<i class="icon-tab-num" data="2"></i>
Account Details
</a>